# Alternative methods to trigonometric equations

Tags: hyperbolic-functions

I've been given the the question

The length $L$ of a heavy cable hanging under gravity is given you the equation

$L=2\sinh x + 3\cosh x$

$L$ is given as $5$

I have working this out into a quadratic formula and found the answer.

I have been asked to check the answer using an alternative method. Could anyone help me out

Carl

Comment: This doesn't look like trigonometry to me, these are hyperbolic functions (e-powers)

Answer (score 1):

**Method I**
\begin{align*}
  2\sinh x+3\cosh x &= 5 \\
  2\left( \frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{2} \right)+
  3\left( \frac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{2} \right) &= 5 \\
  (2+3)e^{2x}+(3-2) &= 10e^{x} \\
  5e^{2x}-10e^{x}+1 &= 0 \\
  e^{x} &= \frac{10\pm \sqrt{10^2-4(5)(1)}}{2(5)} \\
  &= 1 \pm \frac{\sqrt{80}}{10} \\
  &= 1 \pm \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}} \\
  x &= \ln \left( 1\pm \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}} \right)
\end{align*}

**Method II**
\begin{align*}
  \sqrt{a^2-b^2} \cosh \left( x+\tanh^{-1} \frac{b}{a} \right) &=
  a\cosh x+b\sinh x \; ,
  \qquad a>|b| \\
  2\sinh x+3\cosh x &= 5 \\
  \sqrt{3^2-2^2} \cosh \left( x+\tanh^{-1} \frac{2}{3} \right)
  &= 5 \\
  \cosh \left( x+\tanh^{-1} \frac{2}{3} \right) &=
  \sqrt{5} \\
  x+\tanh^{-1} \frac{2}{3} &= \pm \cosh^{-1} \sqrt{5} \\
  x &= \pm \cosh^{-1} \sqrt{5}-\tanh^{-1} \frac{2}{3} \\
  &= \pm \ln (\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{5-1})-
     \ln \sqrt{\frac{1+\frac{2}{3}}{1-\frac{2}{3}}} \\
  &= \pm \ln (\sqrt{5}+2)-\ln \sqrt{5} \\
  &= \ln (\sqrt{5} \pm 2)-\ln \sqrt{5} \\
  &= \ln \left( 1\pm \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}} \right)
\end{align*}

Comment: The *OP already found* the solutions using the quadratic formula. The OP is  looking for an alternative means of solving this.

Comment: OK! Let's use the compound angle formula